# all critical points of $ f(x) = 12.9 x^2 e^{-0.1x} $

Tags: calculus, functions

all critical points of $$ f(x) = 12.9 x^2 e^{-0.1x} $$

help I'm up to the derivative:

$ -0.1 e^{-0.1x} \times (25.8 x + 12.9x^2) $

Comment: If $f'(x)=0$ then $x=?$

Answer (score 2):

You're close on the derivative, but note that by the product rule, we have $$\begin{align} f'(x) & = 25.8x\Big(e^{-0.1x}\Big) + 12.9x^2\Big(-0.1e^{-0.1 x}\Big) \\ \\ & e^{-0.1x}\cdot(25.8x - 1.29x^2) = e^{-0.1x}\Big(x(25.8 - 1.29x)\Big)\end{align}$$

Now we look for when the derivative equals $0$. $e^{-0.1x} \neq  0$, for any value $x$. So the only way $f'(x) = 0$ is if the factor $x\Big(25.8 - 1.29x\Big) = 0$:

Now, $$f'(x) = 0 \implies \Big(x = 0\quad \text{or}\qquad 25.8 - 1.29x = 0 \implies x = 20\Big)$$

Comment: Nice catch and write-up +1

Answer (score 1):

Now that you have the derivative, you just need to find where it is zero.  The factors $-0.1$ and $e^{-0.1x}$ are never zero, so just look for zeros of the last factor.

Comment: The derivative given by the OP is *not correct*.

Answer (score 0):

First off, your derivative is wrong. Using chain rule of derivation; you'll get:

$$ f'(x) = e^{-0.1x} \times ( \color{#FF0000} {-1.29} x^2 + 25.8 x ) $$

Now, set $ f'(x)  = 0 $ and find the values of $ x $ satisfying the condition. $$ f'(x) \equiv 12.9 \times e^{-0.1x} \times x (- 0.1 x + 2) = 0 $$